# Azure OAuth2 Client Credential flow - getting token for multiple scopes throws error

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

When using the MSAL library to generate access token for a background console application, using client_credentials, to call two REST endpoints, the get token call is created as:

```
client_id=XXX&client_info=1&client_secret=XXXX&scope=api%3A%2F%2FMyService-DevBlr-ClientServices%2F.default+api%3A%2F%2FMyService-DevBlr-CoreServices%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and posted to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/a1326aec-378e-4433-8e2a-67a086554fc8/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

The response is a 400 error:

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"AADSTS70011: The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope api://MyService-DevBlr-ClientServices/.default api://MyService-DevBlr-CoreServices/.default is not valid.\r\nTrace ID: 203ad632-5e7c-4e61-9dcd-185eb9b49200\r\nCorrelation ID: 99fd979a-2c11-485b-ba14-c0cad3312e02\r\nTimestamp: 2020-01-11 08:36:29Z","error_codes":[70011],"timestamp":"2020-01-11 08:36:29Z","trace_id":"203ad632-5e7c-4e61-9dcd-185eb9b49200","correlation_id":"99fd979a-2c11-485b-ba14-c0cad3312e02"}
```

When individual scopes are passed in, the call works ok:

```
Request:
client_id=XXXX&client_info=1&client_secret=XXXX&scope=api%3A%2F%2FMyService-DevBlr-CoreServices%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials 

Response:
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"eyJ0e..."}
```

and

```
Request: 
client_id=XXXX&client_info=1&client_secret=XXXX&scope=api%3A%2F%2FMyService-DevBlr-ClientServices%2F.default&grant_type=client_credentials

Response:
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"eyJ0eX..."}
```

The documentation and the API supports scopes array:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#code-snippet

There is benefit in getting a single token to be used with multiple service calls, but I can't seem to get this working. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: A token is generated for a specific audience. In your case, you need to call the function 2 times with different scopes each time and then use the tokens accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you acquire an access token, you can only specify scopes for one API.
It seems to me you are trying to acquire a token with permissions to 2 APIs.
This is not possible.

An access token always only contains permissions to one API.
So you must request them separately.

This is due to a token having an audience (aud) claim that identifies the API it is meant for.
It cannot have two values.

Comment: Makes sense. The documentation is not very clear so I could not confirm this behavior. Thanks, saved me time troubleshooting this

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Anyone know why scopes in this context, is an array of strings?  This implies that you can pass in multiple scopes.  This is what threw me off at first.

Comment: You can pass multiple scopes for _one API_

Comment: Doesn't really make sense in client credentials flow context though

Comment: @juunas - You say you can pass multiple scopes for one API. I am trying to do just that but I cannot find out how!