# Adding custom claims to access token issued by Azure ad

Tags: azure-active-directory

im building an web application with next.js i configured its authentication with auth.js with azure ad provider. now im getting accesstoken from there, and i want to pretect with that token my backend asp.net web api, but to do this i need to have custom claims in that token, about department, jobtitle, companyName from azure active directory.
So from here is a deep forest of azure portal where i cant understand how to configure my azure ad app with that custom claims.

Some tutorials i used was near the thing what i need but i faced some error in next js:

> error_description: 'AADSTS50146: This application is required to be configured with an application-specific signing key

what i just did to the app i went to enterprise application > Single sign-on > Attributes & Claims > Edit > (added user.companyname, user.department, user.jobtitle)

after that my program stopped with that error.

now im looking for solution to make it work and to have those attributes encoded in that jwt access-token

i also did i app registration in Manage: Manifest

> "acceptMappedClaims": true,

but that step of application-specifi signing key i dont understand a thing what is it used for how to create it or add this to make it work. any suggestions? or any guides that explain things in human readable language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran the application without setting **`"acceptMappedClaims": true,`** property in Manifest:

[image]

> The error still occurs if you changed the setting in Next JS web application but **missed** changing in **Web API** app registration.

To **resolve** the error, make sure to change below properties in **`Manifest`** tab of **both** app registrations like this:

```json
{
    "acceptMappedClaims": true,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
}
```

**NextJSApp:**

[image]

**Web API:**

[image]

As you are generating token with **Exposed API** scope, make sure to add claims in **`Web API`** application like this:

*Go to Microsoft Entra ID -> Enterprise Applications -> Select Web API app -> Single sign-on -> Attributes & Claims -> Edit -> Add Claims*

[image]

In **NextJSApp** application, make sure to add Web API permission and grant admin consent to it:

[image]

Now, I ran the web application again and got **tokens** in the console like this:

[image]

When I decoded this **access token** in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website, I got the **custom claims** named *companyName*, *jobtitle* and *department* successfully like this:

[image]

Comment: You have exactly the working sample, what i need, would it be possible to share it on github , the next js app code. cause now after adding scopes and etc . i get errors and i cant even run dev server. all those errors appear in node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js...

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible to share mine on GitHub as there are some blockers at my end. You can share your GitHub repo link here so that I can check and let you know if any changes are required.

Comment: i think the problem in my code is cause of missing image picture information from default token. because when i dig deeper to the nextjs code in function: AzureAD there is a call to graph api to get image. and now when i try to get access-token to the api it does not get access-token to graph api. Is it posible to configure to get one token that suites them both ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to get single token for multiple APIs. Alternatively, you can make use of on-behalf flow to generate token. Refer these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692988/azure-oauth2-client-credential-flow-getting-token-for-multiple-scopes-throws-e and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440605/combine-or-call-two-apis-at-once-multiple-scope/76444913#76444913

Comment: Thank You for your fast responses and help. I have read those references, could you approve or deny am im thinking right on my strategy on solving my problem:
i would leave defaults in provider settings without changing scopes and get at first access-token for msgraph, that image and etc would work without crashing my next js app, but in session or jwt callback i will make additional call with other scope to get access-token for api, and then i can add it to my session ?

Comment: You saved my life @Sridevi - I never thought that I need to also configure API app to accept those claims, as the token is acquired via client app - the token doesn't have those claims however.. only once I setup the API app as well did it come as claim in the token to the client app.. I don't see any logic in that but whatever