How to authenticate an ASP.NET Core Web API using Azure AD token and custom claims from ASP.NET MVC app?
I have two applications: one built with ASP.NET MVC and the other an ASP.NET Core Web API. Users log in to the ASP.NET MVC application using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). Upon successful login, I receive an Azure AD token. I want to use this token to authenticate requests to the Web API application.
However, I also need to add custom claims to this token. These claims are stored in my database and I want the API to have access to them.
Here's the flow I'm trying to implement:

User logs in to the MVC app using Azure AD
I retrieve the token from Azure AD
I add custom claims from my database to this token
The Web API authenticates using the Azure AD token and accesses the custom claims

I have a table UserClaims in my database for the custom claims. How can I ensure that the Web API recognizes these custom claims? Do I need to use IClaimsTransformation in both the MVC and API apps? How can I correctly set these custom claims on the token retrieved from Azure AD?
Is this approach feasible, and if so, what are the best practices to achieve this?
Additional information:

Both applications are secured using Azure AD
The custom claims need to be dynamically retrieved and attached to the token after login.

Thank you for your guidance!

Firstly, Azure AD has its own authorization scheme we can follow this section. We need to expose API and then generate access token containing corresponding  scope or role and then validated by API. These can be done by SDK. In your scenario, you are trying to add custom claims, I'm afraid we'd better to use custom jwt authentication scheme in API project instead of keep using AAD auth scheme,becaue the claim comes from your database instead of AAD.

But if you are trying to add claim for each user in Azure, then  you might take refer to this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78048072/14574199

My idea is that, after users sign in MVC application with their microsoft account, we already know who he/she is and we could get the corresponding claims from the database, then we could generate the jwt token by ourselves, and then in the API application, let's validate the custom claims. Here's my code.
In the MVC application, we could use codes below to generate access token with the claims we required.
public string generateJwt() {
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, "username1"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new Claim("role","admin")
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication"));

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "Test.com",
        audience: "Test.com",
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
        claims: claims,
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );

    var accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

    return accessToken;
}

We can add the bearer token into Authorization request header to call the API. In API project, we should add jwt auth scheme, and add [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdmin")] attribute before the secured action method.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;
using WebApiJwt.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = "Test.com",
            ValidAudience = "Test.com",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is my custom Secret key for authentication")),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, RoleTokenHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdmin", policy =>
         policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement("admin")));
});
builder.Services.AddControllers();

Here's the related validation method, we could refer to the policy based auth scheme in asp.net core.
namespace WebApiJwt.Services
{
    public class RoleTokenHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RoleRequirement>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RoleRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                var httpContext = (DefaultHttpContext)context.Resource;
                if (httpContext != null)
                {
                    string jwtToken = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
                    jwtToken = jwtToken.Substring(7, jwtToken.Length -7);
                    JwtSecurityToken token = DecryptToken(jwtToken);

                    var claims = token.Claims;
                    if (token.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "role" && c.Value == requirement.MyRole).Count() > 0)
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    else
                    {
                        context.Fail();
                        //context.Fail();
                        //context.Succeed(requirement);
                        //throw new NullReferenceException("my custom message");
                    }

                }
                else
                    context.Fail();
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public JwtSecurityToken DecryptToken(string token)
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtSecurityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);
            return jwtSecurityToken;
        }
    }

    public class RoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public RoleRequirement(string role) =>
            MyRole = role;

        public string MyRole { get; }
    }
}


I agree with you. I use the same logic in my implementation, but I'm concerned about whether this is the right approach.

I think this is the right approach as AAD authorization doesn't support your custom requirement. It shall reduce much effort by implementing JWT auth by ourselves.
